# Github action by ssh ionos

Tags: php, ssh, server, github-actions, ionos

I have a problem to deploy a symfony project with github action. I can connect with ssh and execute a git pull or a php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate, but it's impossible to use the compose command.

I followed the various explanations of ionos (https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-development/using-php-composer-in-ionos-webhosting-packages/) but github actions tells me "Could not open input file: composer.phar".

Here is my script if anyone has an idea

```
name: CD
 on:
   push:
     branches: [ develop ]

 jobs:
   deploy:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
       - name: SSH and Deploy
         uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
         with:
           host: ${{ secrets.APP_HOST }}
           username: ${{ secrets.APP_USER }}
           password: ${{ secrets.APP_PASS }}
           port: 22
           script: |
             cd /homepages/14/d800745077/htdocs/clickandbuilds/dashJob
             git pull
             /usr/bin/php8.0-cli composer.phar i
             /usr/bin/php8.0-cli bin/console d:m:m -n
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your current working directory.
If the repository has `composer.phar` in your remote repository you just pulled, then the command would work.

If not, replace it with a `find . -name "composer.phar"` to check *where* that file is in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

IONOS is offering a tooling named [Deploy Now](https://www.ionos.com/hosting/deploy-now) that should ease your setup. For PHP you can find docs [here](https://docs.ionos.space/docs/deploy-php-apps/).